# db service connection error when Docker Compose Up

Tags: python, django, docker

Right now I am working on containerize my Python django app with docker. I has two services in docker-compose file: `web` and `db`. And web service depends on the db service. While I ran `docker-compose build` is fine but when I ran `docker-compose up`, the `web` service always error out with error:

```
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
web_1  |     self.run()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
web_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     if self.has_table():
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
web_1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
web_1  |     return self._cursor()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Another thing is: I noticed a lot people also added `environment` to the `web` service with
:

```
 - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=axasxaxa
```

where are these `DB_HOST, DB_USER` etc comes from? Can we name it as `DB_HOST` but not `DB_HOST_test` or something else?

Last this is my `docker-compose file`:

```
#python manage.py wait_for_db &&
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=realestate
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xsxs
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c 'python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/code/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=xsxs
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: You can name those environment variables however you want for the web container, but in your Django settings file, where the DB connection info is, you need to use `os.environ.get('DB_HOST')` etc to put the connection details in.

I'm also not 100% sure that you can use `env_file` AND `environment` in a compose file.

Do you see output from your db service at all? Maybe do `docker ps` to see it's status

Comment: Thanks @LaurenBoland !! Followed ur suggestions and used `os.environ.get('DB_HOST')` etc in my settings file solved my issue! since the comment cannot be marked as answer, so if u can post an answer below same with ur comment, i can just mark it!

Comment: I'm glad! Docker can be a bear to get set up.